# How to use %x% wildcard in python using SQL

Tags: python, mysql, sql, wildcard

```
input_uni = request.form.get("search")
uni = db.execute("SELECT * FROM unis WHERE name LIKE :name OR country LIKE :country", name=input_uni, country=input_uni)
```

Comment: Does `name=f"%{inpunt_uni}%"` do what you want?

Comment: Yes it did, Thank you so much jordamn

Answer (score 1):

You clould use concat around you param name  for build a proper like pattern without % issues

```
SELECT * FROM unis WHERE name LIKE concat('%', :name, '%')  
   OR country LIKE concat('%', :country, '%');
```

Comment: Does using `concat()` have implications on index usage?

Comment: yes ..  the use of function don't allow the use of index ..  ....but also the use of wildchar in like  produce bad  performance .. so  for like operator the use of caoncat  is not so bad